# Setting Up Postgres on Mac. (Heroku Guidelines)

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I have downloaded postgres but do not understand the last part of the instructions. What do I need to do? See screenshot below. Following instructions here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#set-up-postgres-on-mac

[image: Instructions I don't understand]

Comment: Avoid posting screenshots on stackoverflow. Its easier for us if you type up what is in your screenshot.

Comment: Most probably you should add what you've posted in your `bash_profile`. You can do so by opening a terminal and type `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`. Then you can add that line.

Comment: @A Busy Programmer Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @thanasissdr After I type in sudo nano ~/.bash_profile the terminal asks for a password. I do not know what to enter.

Comment: @digi_life Try the password you use when you log in to the computer as an admin.

Comment: @thanasissdr Ok it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @digi_life You are welcome!